# C++, using memory leaks to advantage?

Tags: c++, oop, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am new to oop and am trying to work out if what I am doing is working well, or very bad programming.

I am dynamically allocating memory to an object of a derived class. But I want to be able to do this repeatedly when necessary using the same part of the code.
I have a simple user interface where the user chooses an option to add an entry to a list (which is a vector). However, I need to be able to do this as many times as required.
So this is the necessary part of my code:

```
case 1:
    Entry * entry = new list_entry;
    list.push_back(entry);
    continue;
```

This is actually doing what I want, but I am concerned that it constitutes a memory leak, in that I never delete the memory. I have read that once the pointer to the object goes out of scope, the memory can no longer be deleted. But this is essentially what I want because I want to be able to use the same pointer name but to point to a different memory address. Otherwise I wouldn't be able to create new pointers to the varying numbers of new objects determined during runtime.

Is this correct, or am I on the wrong track? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's a memory leak if you never delete. But why are you using pointers and dynamic memory at all? You can create objects in C++ without using new

```
std::vector<list_entry> list;

case 1:
    Entry entry;
    list.push_back(entry);
    continue;
```

No pointers, no memory leak.

Comment: Yes, true. I may have oversimplified my question. I need the pointers and dynamic memory because the class list_entry is derived from class Entry. I actually have other derived classes for which I want to be able to add objects of in a similar way.

Comment: Of course, this still allocates ever more memory. If you could/should shrink that data structure but fail to, it's still a memory leak - just a so-called *logical* memory leak (the kind neither Valgrind nor a GC can save you from). Apart from that, I don't really see how this answers the question. It's a good suggestion in general, but it doesn't address OP's doubt (-1).

Comment: @delnan I would assume that at some point the list goes out of scope. At that point the memory is freed.

Comment: @user2308968 OK fair point. There's a C++ class shared_ptr which will free the memory for you when it's no longer being referenced, `std::vector<shared_ptr<list_entry>>`

Answer (score 1):

You can free memory, by deleting pointers, contained in `list` manually, when you don't need this list anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This is not yet a memory leak, because you store the pointer in your list. This means you can still access the memory, and delete it at a later time.

Just make sure that before you delete or clear the list, you iterate through it and delete all the entries.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually NOT losing track to the objects, because the pointers remain in `list`. So, there is no need to delete them instantly.
Just make sure to delete them when you don't need them in the `list` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

> But this is essentially what I want because I want to be able to use the same pointer name but to point to a different memory address. Otherwise I wouldn't be able to create new pointers to the varying numbers of new objects determined during runtime.

I believe what is going on is a disconnect between your perception of what calling `delete` does and what actually happens. When `delete` is called, the memory a pointer *points* to is deleted. The pointer itself is still there. You should think of pointers as numbers *referring to* a location, but not the location itself.

To illustrate this, let's take a simple example. Say we have pointer `foo *p`, and we do `p = new foo`. Now, `p` equals memory location `0x3a` where an object of type `foo` is located. You then call `delete p`. The object *it points to is deleted*, but p itself is untouched. In fact, `p` still equals `0x3a`, but that location in memory now contains empty space, ready to be used for something else (this is not strictly true, but it's easier to think this way). You can now do `p = new foo`, and `p` will point to some new space - maybe even the old, now empty, space - where another `foo` is allocated.

In conclusion: `delete p` destroys the object p points to, but does not destroy `p`, the pointer itself, thus freeing up the memory that object took up. If you want to destroy `p`, the pointer, then you can erase it from the list. So, if you want to reuse pointers, first destroy the object they point to, and then allocate a new object. (Or use smart pointers, as suggested above.)